# HP ALM QC: recalculate run status in dependence of run-step stati with REST API

Tags: rest, api, hp-alm

we create/update tests, test-instances and runs with REST API. A problem I now ran into is that the status of a run is not updated if I update the stati of run-steps. If you do it in the application itself it works. Is there a way to achieve the same with the REST API? I tried to update the run without the field "status" set, but this won't trigger a recalculation.

Comment: Are you sure when you change run-steps it automatically changes status of run. See, there are two status run-status which is at run level and another is test-instance status which is latest status of test case execution

Comment: sorry for the late answer: I figured that these stati are completely independent from each other. Although if you manually enter the stati of run steps HP QC will update the status of the run according to a weird rule set. But I left it to the testers to set those stati individually when importing their data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. Do you mean that the Run Status should be updated, when you update the Run Step Status in a Test Run?  If so, I don’t think it works on both QC Client UI and REST UI. 
The reason is ‘Run Steps’ are steps only in the Run time. When this run finishes, the QC will calculate an overall Run Status based on all these Run Step Status. If you want to modify the Run Step Status in this Run (Select a Test Run -> Go to Run Details -> Steps -> Modify some Step Status), the Run Status is not affected, because those Run Steps status was not modified during the Run Time. 
But, if you ‘Re-run’ the Run, and modify the Run Step status during the run time, the Run status was affected.